# AWS Amplify DataStore causes syncing issues on login

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, datastore

## Context

I am using AWS Amplify for a full-stack website. The front end is React JS made by Create-React-App. I use the Amplify DataStore between the AppSync GraphQl API and the application. The website manages tutors and clients to find peer tutoring sessions. In the database, there are `Client` and `Tutor` models, each with a field called `authToken`. Each person's Cognito login user has a `sub` token which is linked to the `authToken` field in the database.

The App Sync has permissions which allow for unauthenticated and authenticated users to access to the data.

```
type Client @model @auth(rules: [{allow: groups, groups: ["admins"], operations: [read, create, update, delete]}, {allow: private}, {allow: public, operations: [read]}, {allow: private, provider: iam}]) {
  id: ID!
  email: AWSEmail!
  firstName: String!
  lastName: String!
  authToken: String!
  phone: AWSPhone
  credits: Float!
  Students: [Student] @hasMany(indexName: "byClient", fields: ["id"])
}

type Tutor @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public, operations: [read, create, update]}, {allow: groups, groups: ["admins"], operations: [read, create, update, delete]}, {allow: groups, groups: ["tutors"], operations: [read, update, delete, create]}, {allow: private}, {allow: private, provider: iam}]) {
  id: ID!
  email: AWSEmail!
  firstName: String!
  lastName: String!
  authToken: String!
  phone: AWSPhone
}
```

## Problem

In production, tutors have reported issues logging into their dashboards. Either the data doesn't load, or they are greeted with a warning screen saying that their `Tutor` model cannot be found.

Current code

```
/**
 * Takes a call back function which when the data syncing is ready, will be called to return the current user's tutor model id, if the current user is a tutor
 */
export async function setCurrentUserTutorCallback(
  setUser: (tutor: LazyTutor | null) => void
) {
  let sub = await getCurrrentUserSub();
  if (!sub || sub == null) {
    console.log(`Cannot find tutor id for sub: ${sub}`);
    setUser(null);
    return null;
  } else {
    // @ts-ignore
    DataStore.observeQuery(Tutor, (t) => t.authToken.eq(sub)).subscribe(
      async (snapshot) => {
        const { items, isSynced } = snapshot;

        if (isSynced) {
          if (items.length === 1) {
            setUser(items[0]);
          } else if (items.length === 0) {
            setUser(null);
            console.log("No tutor found for sub: " + sub);
          } else {
            setUser(null);
            console.error(`Found ${items.length} tutors for sub: ${sub}`);
            await createAnalytic("ERROR", {
              component: "authUtilities",
              function: "setCurrentUserTutorCallback",
              error: `Found ${items.length} tutors for sub: ${sub}`,
            });
          }
        }
      }
    );
  }
  return null;
}

export default function ClientDashboard() {
  const [tutor, setTutor] = useState<LazyTutor | null>(null);
  const [isLoadingTutor, setIsLoadingTutor] = useState(false);

  // used as a callback to get the current user's tutor id from a query observer in DataStore

  const setTutorCallback = (tutor: LazyTutor | null) => {
    if (tutor) {
      setTutor(tutor);
      setIsLoadingTutor(false);
      console.log("SET tutor id: " + tutor.id + " and name " + tutor.firstName);
    } else {
      setTutor(null);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUserTutorId = () => {
      setCurrentUserTutorCallback(setTutorCallback);
    };
    getUserTutorId();
  }, []);
}

if (!tutor) {
  if (isLoadingTutor) {
    return (... a blinking placeholder box)
  } else {
    return (<h1> can't find your tutor client!</h1>
  }
} else {
  return (<div> normal looking dashboard </div>
}
```

The current frontend is now showing that the tutor's client model isn't loading, thus showing them they can't log in. I'm stumped because I thought by allowing for loading tutor data publically and privately, then using a `Datastore.observeQuery()`, it would wait until the data is synced, then return their tutor model.